Routing issue between peered VNets and VPN

In order for me to more easily explain, I have added the above graph.
A more detailed explanation of my issue follows:

I have 2 virtual networks, VNet1 and VNet2, that are peered. Connectivity between them is verified and tested (2-ways).
I have a VPN tunnel connecting VNet2 to the Remote Network, using a VPN gateway (S2S). Connectivity between VNet2 and the Remote network is verified and tested.
There is no connectivity from VNet1 towards the Remote Network.

Connectivity from VNet1 to the Remote Network doesn't work with the original/vanilla configuration. So far I have tried:

Manually added a route for the Remote Network in the Route Table for VNet1 (next hop type is "Virtual network gateway").
Created a Route Table for VNet2 and added a route for the Remote Network (next hop type is "Virtual network gateway").
Experimented with all possible options for "next hop type".
Set the peering options for VNet1 to have "Enable 'VNet1' to use 'VNet2's' remote gateway or route server" to "enabled".

Nothing of the above has worked. I still have no way to access the Remote Network from VNet1.
To make matters worse, the below KB appears to me to imply that by setting everything as I have, the connectivity would be there without additional configuration:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit
Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to assist.
